# MONGO How to convert 2 geo fields to one "array"?

Tags: mongodb, collections

I have a mongodb collection with thousands of "records" with latitute and longitude, for instance:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50ad4f686579e337e1ec2294"), "place" : "Portugal", "lat" : 41.8343, "lon" : -8.3342 }
```

How to update all collection "records" to be put the lat and lon inside a new field called location like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50ad4f686579e337e1ec2294"), "place" : "Portugal", "location": {"lat" : 41.8343, "lon" : -8.3342 } }
```

Regards
fak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can not do this just using update.

You have to iterate through all the documents and update in place:

```
db.coll.find().forEach(
  function (doc) {
    doc.location = { lat: doc.lat, lon: doc.lon };
    delete doc.lat;
    delete doc.lon;
    db.coll.save(doc);
  }
)
```

Another option can be to do this programmatically. Going through each document. Copy it using programming language of your choice and update each of the documents the way you want

P.S when you ask someone to help - make sure that you do not have errors in your starting code. It took me quite a while to spot missing "